# Ruby on Rails: Should I move this code into the model? If so, what's the best way?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

I'm new to rails. I have a relatively simple question. I have defined a controller that manages friend requests. In the create action, I check to see if the other user has already sent a friend request to the current user. If so, I skip creating another friend request and simply execute the logic that accepts the friend request that already exists. Here is my code:

```
class FriendRequestsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def create
    current_user_id = current_user.id;
    recipient_id = params[:recipient_id].to_i;

    # check if the other person has already sent a friend request
    unless (existing_request = FriendRequest.find_by(
        :sender_id => recipient_id,
        :recipient_id => current_user_id)).nil?
      accept(existing_request)
      return redirect_to current_user
    end

    request = FriendRequest.new(:sender_id => current_user_id,
                                :recipient_id => recipient_id)
    if request.save
      flash[:notice] = "Sent friend request."
    else
      flash[:errors] = request.errors.full_messages
    end
    redirect_to users_path

  end
```

Should some of the above logic go into the FriendRequest model, instead? If so, how much of it? Is there a good* way I can move the call to FriendRequest.new and request.save into the model, as well, while still maintaining the necessary degree of control in the controller?

*What I mean by "good" is: standard, ruby-ish, rails-ish, easily recognizable, familiar-to-many, popular, accepted, etc.

Is there anything else about my code that stands out as poor practice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This right here could be improved a bit:

```
 unless (existing_request = FriendRequest.find_by(
        :sender_id => recipient_id,
        :recipient_id => current_user_id)).nil?
```

Instead, you could write a method in the friend request model:

```
def self.find_matching_request(sender_id, receiver_id)
  find_by(sender_id: sender_id, receiver_id: receiver_id)
end
```

This doesn't really save you many keystrokes for this example but it's the type of thing you'd do if you wanted to move logic out of the controller and into the model. Basically making a method which is a wrapper for database interaction logic. The bulk of database interaction is supposed to be done in the model, though many people end up doing it in the controller.

Then in the controller:

```
existing_request = find_matching_request(current_user_id, recipient_id) 
if existing_request
  accept(existing_request)
  redirect_to current_user
end
```

Before you were using `unless <some_val>.nil?` which looks like an antipattern unless you're treating `false` and `nil` differently for some reason. More typical would be `if <some_val>`